# best practises for positioning css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, position

I have started getting into web development and have created a first draft for my website [siavoush-re.co.uk,](http://siavoush-re.co.uk) however the more research I do the more I realise the methods I have used for positioning is not good.

1. is positioning with margins better than using relative/absolute 
   positioning?
2. What is best practise when positioning elements, especially for responsive design?
3. What methods should I avoid using or are outdated?

Answer (score 3):

1. Margins and paddings are better than positioning use % unit for responsive designs.
2. You can use position:relative; for the responsive design as BOOTSTRAP also use this positioning,but using absolute positioning will move your content when you view on a small device.
3. Avoid using pt or px unit for font-size, use 'EM'

Comment: 1) Does positioning with margin increase the width of the page? Also for a design like mine, how would you personally position your elements?

Comment: Apply display:inline-block. on the header parent, and will move the nav links to the right. Look at the screenshot -> http://prntscr.com/7nv6cf

Wrap the nav links in a ul and give padding to the whole ul.

Answer (score 1):

Relative and absolute positioning isn’t bad per se, sometimes useful, but just incredibly easy to do wrong.

You want multiple columns. Traditionally, we use the `float` property for that, as legacy browsers support it well. There are a couple of new properties that will allow you to create columns as well, but legacy browsers do not support them, so for now I would personally discourage use unless you’re absolutely sure your visitors run modern browsers and you don’t care if the site fails on legacy browsers.

## The Easy Way

Either way, floating in CSS is tough. I would highly recommend a responsive grid system. There are many CSS downloads available. All you have to do is use the appropriate classes for your columns.

- Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/ (comes with a lot of extras, so use with caution)
- Skeleton: http://getskeleton.com/
- Pure.css: http://purecss.io/
- Responsive Grid System: http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/

There are tons more.

---

## The Hard Way

By far, floating is the most popular choice. Floating elements causes block elements (like divs) to sit aside. You apply a width to each column, and voila, you have multiple columns. Doing sizing with gutters and paddings is slightly annoying, hence I recommend using an existing stylesheet that does it all for you. Basically, after several columns, you will have to append an element with the `clear` property to fix the layout flow.

Alternatively, depending on your target audience, you can use CSS [columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns), [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) or [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/grid).

---

## Why Not Use Absolute/Relative?

Browsers sort out the flow for you. Growing elements will push down anything that comes after. Relative positioning doesn’t change this behaviour, but absolute positioning does. It just smacks the element on top of your stuff, and you will have to make room for you content yourself.

I do use relative/absolute positioning sometimes, but only to make things overlap. For example, I have an image container (relative), that holds an image (absolute) and a title/label (absolute). By having the latter two positioned absolutely, I can move within the container as I like. By setting a size on the container, I can put it anywhere I want without breaking the flow.

Answer (score 0):

- It depends, `relative` position is the positioning of elements
  relative to the actual flow of HTML.
- Whereas `absolute` positioning is in reference the the top-left coordinate of your document. (not always)

  Best practices for responsive layouts?

There is nothing best, you must know when to use `media queries` and use `%` instead of `px` for columns widths and also `float` property.

[Here](http://www.codehelp.co.uk/html/deprecated.html) you can find the list of depreciated properties and tags

Answer (score 0):

Very nice work :)

You can investigate Bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com. I used it recently and with this framerowk you can do amazing responsive websites :) Simply add specified classes and styles to `<div>, <span>, <p>` and other HTML elements.

Comment: Thank you, I know bootstrap is good for responsive, but I want to learn how to do it with css first before moving on the bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

CSS resets help establish a baseline from which all the styles are set. A reset effectively overrides the browsers’ default styles for certain elements (which can vary greatly). Despite the popularity of CSS resets over the past several years, many sites still don’t employ them, and these sites’ CSS scalability is suffering greatly for it.

Instead of using the extremely popular CSS Reset by Eric Meyer (because it is too far-reaching) or making up a DIY reset, many people recommend using normalize.css. Normalize.css “normalizes” the code to a common baseline rather than resetting the base styling for elements across all browsers. Referring to the normalize.css project on Github, these are its advantages over a CSS reset:

Preserves useful defaults, unlike many CSS resets
Normalizes styles for a wide range of HTML elements
Corrects bugs and common browser inconsistencies
Improves usability with subtle improvements
Explains what code does using detailed comments
Using normalize.css in lieu of a standard reset will get you on the right coding foot and save a lot of time in not having to reestablish baseline styles.

[enter link description here](http://www.sitepoint.com/css-architectures-new-best-practices/)

Answer (score 0):

To answer each of your questions in turn:

1. This really depends on the context of the element in the HTML and what you are trying to achieve in the site layout.  Quite simply, there are often multiple solutions to a problem.  Sometimes it is more appropriate to use margins, some solutions are best left to relative positioning, and other times absolute positioning is your only answer.
2. See 1 although I would avoid hard coding widths and heights in pixels: `%` and `em` are commonly used in responsive design.  My best advice would be to follow a few tutorials and see how the CSS works together.  The CSS `media-design` is often used in responsive web design.
3. Best to follow W3C recommendations for outdated HTML and CSS.  From the top of my head, you should avoid using `<table>` tags to define site layout.

Interesting read: http://www.w3.org/TR/mobile-bp/